# flutter_tools.snapshot daemon starts automatically and burning my CPU, what is it?

Tags: flutter

I am on MacOS and I am not running any flutter processes manually and have quitted VS Code editor successfully. But in Activity Monitor app, I see a `dart` process is running and burning my CPU.

```
ps -ef | grep -i dart
  501 11462     1   0  1:16AM ??        14:51.36 /path/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart /path/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_tools.snapshot daemon
```

What is it? I waited for 15 minutes, it was still running. So I simply killed it.